# is Zend Studio Plugin for eclipse (3.6.1 up) is free?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, zend-studio

Sorry I can't understand well the license agreement.
Here is the link I followed to install Zend Studio as a Plugin.

[Zend Studio as a Plugin](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/installing_zend_studio_as_a_plugin.htm)

I know that Zend Studio IDE is not free. So taht, I am wondering if the plugin is not a free plugin.

is it

free to use? 
free to create personal/commercial site?
no license violation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Studio is commercial software.  You can install it as a plugin if you have an existing Eclipse-based IDE but you will still be asked for a license key.  [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt), however, is the free version of Zend Studio which has some of the standard code editing features.